# Hot Swappable Power Supply Making Weird Sound

Tags: power-supply-unit

No idea why the server is making this sound and as you can tell, it's very annoying.
Taking out the bad section of the hot swappable power supply does not stop the sound.

Anyone have an idea why it's making this sound?

I took a video of the server in action with all the high pitched whine.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v88KPoj0fCc

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried pulling out the hot swap power supplies one by one to see if once might be generating the noise? Either way, sounds like you need to call the manufacture for a replacement.

Answer (score 1):

> Taking out the bad section of the hot
>   swappable power supply does not stop
>   the sound

By "bad section" I hope you mean an actual power supply module and not some components from within it.

After listening to your little video clip I'm much more inclined to think the problem is with one of your system fans. You can easily confirm this by removing or disconnecting one at a time. Do the same for the power supplies, just to be sure. If none of this fixes the problem, or at least greatly reduces it, then I'd suspect the control system, or one of its sensors, is defective and keeping the fans running at full speed.

Comment: +1 for hearing the same thing I did. :)  I'd give it another for troubleshooting technique but thems the rules.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a whining capacitor which means it could be failing.

You may want to read about ["Percussive Maintenance"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percussive_maintenance) which equates to "find it and hit it."  But if it's in your PSU you really shouldn't be popping that thing open and mucking with it.